# CURL won't connect to self

Tags: php, wget, curl, ssl

I'm having a weird issue where CURL cannot connect to its own server.
For example if I'm on server **example.com**

```
wget https://example.com/  <--- WORKS FIND

curl https://example.com gets error: 35 SSL connect error
```

Curl works for connecting to other external SSL address, but just will not connect to self.

Also curl works for connecting to itself without SSL.

Here is the output from curl -v:

```
curl -v https://example.com/
* About to connect() to example.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 50.70.60.100... connected
* Connected to example.com (50.70.60.100) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* NSS error -12286
* Error in TLS handshake, trying SSLv3...
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.16.2.3 Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: example.com
> Accept: */*
>
* Connection died, retrying a fresh connect
* Closing connection #0
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://example.com/'
* About to connect() to example.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 50.70.60.100... connected
* Connected to example.com (50.70.60.100) port 443 (#0)
* TLS disabled due to previous handshake failure
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* NSS error -12286
* Closing connection #0
* SSL connect error
curl: (35) SSL connect error
```

Comment: It turns out it was a cipher issue.  I tried all kinds of cipher options with CURL with no success, but then realized that there were not sufficient ciphers enabled in Apache (which was also causing SSL issues in Android). 
Changed the ssl cipher settings to:

Comment: `SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3`

`SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> NSS error -12286
> ```

According to [NSS documentation](http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/ref/ssl/sslerr.html), -12286 means:

> SSL_ERROR_NO_CYPHER_OVERLAP
>
> "Cannot communicate securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s)."
>
> The local and remote systems share no cipher suites in common. This can be due to a misconfiguration at either end. It can be due to a server being misconfigured to use a non-RSA certificate with the RSA key exchange algorithm.

You could try telling curl which cipher to use with its `--ciphers` option.

See [here](https://superuser.com/a/224263/13781) for one way to enumerate the list of ciphers the server supports (or check the web server's configuration, if you have access to it).